# ERROR_TYPE : ERROR - ERROR_CODE:INVALID_SCRIPT_ID- MessageA saved search with the script ID 267 does not exist

Tags: netsuite

Hi i am working with netsuite and I am doing location search advance. I am not able to get the saved search access based on ID when i calling using my program it is throwing the below error:

```html
ERROR_TYPE : ERROR - ERROR_CODE:INVALID_SCRIPT_ID- MessageA saved search with the script ID 267 does not exist..
```

I just want to know how can i get the saved search access based on ID.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: LocationSearchAdvanced locationSearchAdvanceCriteria = new LocationSearchAdvanced();
  
  locationSearchAdvanceCriteria.setSavedSearchScriptId("customsearch239945");
  // locationSearchAdvanceCriteria.setSavedSearchId("267");
  
  return locationSearchAdvanceCriteria;

Comment: and i am able to see the ID of my saved search when i am executing it from the netsuite , but when the same ID i am trying to get it from the code getting the above error

Comment: is the search public?

Comment: yes it is public , now its working with the following script it is returning [ ] empty one record , but when i am viewing it in NetSuite it is displaying one record

Comment: are the roles same in SOAP and UI?